# JavaScript OnClick() start karaoke text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to work with a karaoke theme where there is song playing and text is reading. The issue I am having is that when the page loads the karaoke starts automatically. I would like to make a button function which allows the user to press it and then the text starts to follow the karaoke pattern not when the page loads.

```js
var songtext;
$(document).ready(function() {
    songtext = [ // [text, duration]
        ["My Little Pony, My Little Pony", 1500],
        ["</br> Ahh, ahh, ahh, ahhh...", 1500],
        ["</br> (My Little Pony)", 3500],
        ["</br> I used to wonder what friendship could be", 1500],
        ["</br> (My Little Pony)", 3500],
        ["</br> Until you all shared its magic with me", 1500],
        ["</br> Big adventure", 900],
        ["</br> Tons of fun", 900],
        ["</br> A beautiful heart", 900],
        ["</br> Faithful and strong", 900],
        ["</br> Sharing kindness!", 900],
        ["</br> It's an easy feat", 900],
        ["</br> And magic makes it all complete", 900],
        ["</br> You have my little ponies", 900],
        ["</br> Do you know you're all my very best friends?", 1000],
        ["</br> My Little Pony", 800],
        ["</br> My Little Pony", 800],
        ["</br> My Little Pony... friends", 1000],

    ];
    var text="";
    $.each(songtext, function(a, b) {
        text += "<span id='p"+a+"' style='color:black'>" + b[0] + "</span> ";
    });

    $('#div').html(text);

    cc=0;

    nextWord();
});

var cc = 0;
function nextWord() {
    $('#p'+cc).css("color", "blue");
    cc++;
    if(cc> songtext.length-1) return;
    window.setTimeout(nextWord, songtext[cc-1][1]);
}
```

```css
#fontstyle {
    font-size: 20pt;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.lint--old/blob/master/jquery.lint.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div"></div>

<button type="button">Play</button>
```

Comment: So the question is how to attach a function to a click? How could this possibly not be available via google?

Comment: That song immediately started playing in my head when I read the JavaScript! (Note: I have a daughter)

Comment: @DivineComedian Yeah this is a project we are building for small children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you call `nextWord` in the `document.ready` handler. Put it inside the button's click handle:

```js
var songtext;
$(document).ready(function() {
  songtext = [ // [text, duration]
    ["My Little Pony, My Little Pony", 1500],
    ["</br> Ahh, ahh, ahh, ahhh...", 1500],
    ["</br> (My Little Pony)", 3500],
    ["</br> I used to wonder what friendship could be", 1500],
    ["</br> (My Little Pony)", 3500],
    ["</br> Until you all shared its magic with me", 1500],
    ["</br> Big adventure", 900],
    ["</br> Tons of fun", 900],
    ["</br> A beautiful heart", 900],
    ["</br> Faithful and strong", 900],
    ["</br> Sharing kindness!", 900],
    ["</br> It's an easy feat", 900],
    ["</br> And magic makes it all complete", 900],
    ["</br> You have my little ponies", 900],
    ["</br> Do you know you're all my very best friends?", 1000],
    ["</br> My Little Pony", 800],
    ["</br> My Little Pony", 800],
    ["</br> My Little Pony... friends", 1000],

  ];
  var text = "";
  $.each(songtext, function(a, b) {
    text += "<span id='p" + a + "' style='color:black'>" + b[0] + "</span> ";
  });

  $('#div').html(text);

  cc = 0;
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nextWord();
  });
});

var cc = 0;

function nextWord() {
  $('#p' + cc).css("color", "blue");
  cc++;
  if (cc > songtext.length - 1) return;
  window.setTimeout(nextWord, songtext[cc - 1][1]);
}
```

```css
#fontstyle {
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.lint--old/blob/master/jquery.lint.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div"></div>

<button type="button">Play</button>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfect also thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `nextWord();` inside `$(document).ready`.

And you can start your karaoke like :

```
<button type="button" onclick='nextWord();'>Play</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add:

```
$('.play').on('click', function() {
  $('#div').html(text);
   cc=0;
  nextWord();
});
```

so that when you click the play button, then the text will show and start the blue text highlighting

```js
var songtext;
$(document).ready(function() {
    songtext = [ // [text, duration]
        ["My Little Pony, My Little Pony", 1500],
        ["</br> Ahh, ahh, ahh, ahhh...", 1500],
        ["</br> (My Little Pony)", 3500],
        ["</br> I used to wonder what friendship could be", 1500],
        ["</br> (My Little Pony)", 3500],
        ["</br> Until you all shared its magic with me", 1500],
        ["</br> Big adventure", 900],
        ["</br> Tons of fun", 900],
        ["</br> A beautiful heart", 900],
        ["</br> Faithful and strong", 900],
        ["</br> Sharing kindness!", 900],
        ["</br> It's an easy feat", 900],
        ["</br> And magic makes it all complete", 900],
        ["</br> You have my little ponies", 900],
        ["</br> Do you know you're all my very best friends?", 1000],
        ["</br> My Little Pony", 800],
        ["</br> My Little Pony", 800],
        ["</br> My Little Pony... friends", 1000],

    ];
    var text="";
    $.each(songtext, function(a, b) {
        text += "<span id='p"+a+"' style='color:black'>" + b[0] + "</span> ";
    });

    $('.play').on('click', function() {
      $('#div').html(text);
       cc=0;
      nextWord();
    });
    

   

    
});

var cc = 0;
function nextWord() {
    $('#p'+cc).css("color", "blue");
    cc++;
    if(cc> songtext.length-1) return;
    window.setTimeout(nextWord, songtext[cc-1][1]);
}
```

```css
#fontstyle {
    font-size: 20pt;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.lint--old/blob/master/jquery.lint.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div"></div>

<button type="button" class="play">Play</button>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't remove the `nextWord()` call from the document's `ready` handler, so it will start as soon as the page loads anyway!

Comment: @ShotgunNinja, how so? `nextWord()` is in the `click` function

Comment: Oh, never mind; I misread your code... unless you made a ninja edit.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var songtext;
$(document).ready(function() {
  songtext = [ // [text, duration]
    ["My Little Pony, My Little Pony", 1500],
    ["</br> Ahh, ahh, ahh, ahhh...", 1500],
    ["</br> (My Little Pony)", 3500],
    ["</br> I used to wonder what friendship could be", 1500],
    ["</br> (My Little Pony)", 3500],
    ["</br> Until you all shared its magic with me", 1500],
    ["</br> Big adventure", 900],
    ["</br> Tons of fun", 900],
    ["</br> A beautiful heart", 900],
    ["</br> Faithful and strong", 900],
    ["</br> Sharing kindness!", 900],
    ["</br> It's an easy feat", 900],
    ["</br> And magic makes it all complete", 900],
    ["</br> You have my little ponies", 900],
    ["</br> Do you know you're all my very best friends?", 1000],
    ["</br> My Little Pony", 800],
    ["</br> My Little Pony", 800],
    ["</br> My Little Pony... friends", 1000],

  ];
  var text = "";
  $.each(songtext, function(a, b) {
    text += "<span id='p" + a + "' style='color:black'>" + b[0] + "</span> ";
  });

  $('#div').html(text);

  cc = 0;
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nextWord();
  });
});

var cc = 0;

function nextWord() {
  $('#p' + cc).css("color", "blue");
  cc++;
  if (cc > songtext.length - 1) return;
  window.setTimeout(nextWord, songtext[cc - 1][1]);
}
```

```css
#fontstyle {
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.lint--old/blob/master/jquery.lint.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div"></div>

<button type="button">Play</button>
```